# Eclipse 4: disable native alt-f4 behavior

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

does anyone know if it is possible to disable or overwrite the native behavior of "alt+f4" (on windows closes the application) in an e4 application? 
what is suggested solution to achieve this?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

My solution is **NOT** pure SWT solution. **It only works on Windows**. But you mentioned Windows, and if you only target one platform this is good enough. It uses internal code from SWT, but it maps to Windows API, documented by Microsoft, so it will not change.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if (OS.GetKeyState(OS.VK_MENU) < 0 && OS.GetKeyState(OS.VK_F4) < 0) {
                event.doit = false;
            }
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution but i am not to happy with that one.
created a addon: 
that is registering an event handler on the `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE` topic.
then somehow retrieve the shell from the topics metadata and registering a filter on the display.

```
@PostConstruct
void hookListeners() {
    eventHandler = new EventHandler() {



        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            MElementContainer property = (MElementContainer) arg0.getProperty("org.eclipse.e4.data");
            final Shell shell = (Shell) property.getSelectedElement().getWidget();
            final Display display = shell.getDisplay();
            display.addFilter(SWT.Close, new Listener() {

                @Override
                public void handleEvent(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event event) {

                    if (!MessageDialog.openQuestion(shell, "Exit",
                            "Do you really want to close the Application?")) {
                        //see api documentation display.addFilter( 
                         event.type = SWT.NONE;
                         event.doit = false;

                    }

                }
            });             
        }
    };
eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, eventHandler);
}
```

this solution does not seem to correct to me so if anyone has a better one please share it :-)